# oboo[12] : How to show logged in user's created invoice only?

Tags: odoo, user-permissions, odoo-12, invoice

When I create another user and give him permission of **Sales = User: Own Documents Only** . He can access only his own data and other permission is **Accounting & Finance = Billing**  for showing the Invoicing menu.

Now my problem is that when this user will create the invoice and open invoice menu at that time he will see all invoices but I want to show him only his created invoices. How to do that if you know please let me know. **Without filter because filter is temporary solution.**

Comment: You need to pass domain in tree view action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter `My Invoices` in the invoice list view.

[image: My Invoices]

Comment: Hi i want does not show any other's invoices. in your case when i remove My Invoices tag after that i can show all invoices.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with domain in record rules like following example :

```
`<record id="account_invoice_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">User Invoices View</field>
    <field ref="account_invoice" name="model_id"/>
    <field name="domain_force">['|',('create_uid','=',False),                              ('create_uid','=',user.id)]/field>
    <field name="active">True</field>
</record>`
```